Is Gridgain9 downstream from ignite2 or ignite3
Is Gridgain9 downstream from ignite2 or ignite3 (I figure that knowing this can help troubleshoot, because one might look for answers from the upstream software as well.)


GridGain 9 is based on Apache Ignite 3
GridGain 8 is based on Apache Ignite 2


Thank you. That's what it seemed like, but I wanted to confirm. Knowing this is useful, when talking to potential clients.

According to https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/whats-new-in-gridgain-9, GridGain 9 is more than an upgrade – it’s a significant leap forward for the Unified Real-Time Data Platform. It is as thorough improvement over GridGain 8 as Apache Ignite 3 is over Apache Ignite 2. https://ignite.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-beta/ shows that Apache Ignite 3 has many new features which are available in GridGain 9 as well.

Thanks. My clients use products that are downstream from open source ones (e.g. downstream from Kafka or Kubernetes). But they're wary of forks that go their own way. So, I'm curious if Gridgain is a downstream product that will continue to incorporate changes made in Ignite, or whether it will go it's own way, and stop being an enhanced and supported Ignite.
